# How are I/O operations defined in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to know how are low level I/O operations defined in Google Cloud SQL, as for their data store they have defined that for one INSERT or UPDATE there are several low level I/O operations that are performed. Is that same for SQL, If yes what are these, Also if my data is replicated across several servers in Cloud SQL, will I be paying the cost of replication, for e.g If my data is spread across 5 servers so will my 1 insert equals to five I/O operations?

Answer (score 4):

An op is defined as a call to read() or fsync().  write() can also trigger an op if there is a lot of buffered data.  You can run mysqld under strace to get an idea of how many ops a query would trigger.  For example, a simple query like

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42);
```

would roughly generate

```
write(logfile, 42);
fsync(logfile);
write(datafile, 42);
fsync(datafile);
```

So that would count as two ops.  Replication is included in the cost, so this counts as just two ops, not 2 * num_replicas.